# which numbers in list 2 are bigger and smaller than each number in list 1

Tags: python, list, search

I am using python. I have two lists, list 1 is 7000 integers long, list 2 is 25000 integers. I want to go through each number in list 1 and find the closest number in list 2 that is bigger and the closest number that is smaller than each number in list 1, and then calculate the difference between these two numbers in list 2. So far I have:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list 2:
        if list2[j]<list1[i]:
            a = max(list2)
        elif list2[j]>list1[i]:
            b = min(list2)
            interval = b-a
```

This doesn't seem to work. I want to find the explicit numbers in list 2 that are less than a specific number in list 1 and know the maximum, and then find out the smallest number in list 2 that is bigger than the number in list 1. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are your lists sorted?

Comment: For starters, `list2[j] < list1[i]` should be simply `j < i`.

Comment: since you have `if..` and `elif...`, each time you iterate through list2 you will only have one of `a` or `b` defined, not both

Comment: If your lists have duplicates, better to convert them to a set first with `set(list1)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `bisect` module, worst case complexity `O(N * logN)`:

```
import bisect
lis1 = [4, 20, 26, 27, 30, 53, 57, 76, 89, 101]
lis2 = [17, 21, 40, 49, 53, 53, 53, 53, 70, 80, 81, 95, 99] #this must be sorted
#use lis2.sort() in case lis2 is not sorted
for x in lis1:
       #returns the index where x can be placed in lis2, keeping lis2 sorted
       ind=bisect.bisect(lis2,x) 
       if not (x >= lis2[-1] or x <= lis2[0]):
           sm, bi = lis2[ind-1], lis2[ind]

           if sm == x:  
               """ To handle the case when an item present in lis1 is 
               repeated multiple times in lis2, for eg 53 in this case"""
               ind -= 1
               while lis2[ind] == x:
                   ind -= 1
               sm = lis2[ind]

           print "{} <= {} <= {}".format(sm ,x, bi)
```

**output:**

```
17 <= 20 <= 21
21 <= 26 <= 40
21 <= 27 <= 40
21 <= 30 <= 40
49 <= 53 <= 70
53 <= 57 <= 70
70 <= 76 <= 80
81 <= 89 <= 95
```

Though this will not output anything for `4` and `101`, as 4 is smaller than any element in lis2 and 101 is greater than any element in lis2. But that can be fixed if required.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a vectorized solution using NumPy.  It should be extremely fast, as it has no loops in Python (apart from the printing stage at the end).

```
import numpy as np

# set up fake data
l1 = np.array([1.9, 2, 2.1]) # or whatever list you have
l2 = np.array([1, 2, 5, 10]) # as above
l2.sort() # remove this line if it's always sorted

# the actual algorithm
indexes = np.searchsorted(l2, l1, side='right')
lower = l2[indexes - 1]
upper = l2[indexes]
diffs = upper - lower

# print results for debugging
for value, diff in zip(l1, diffs):
    print "value", value, "gap", diff
```

Here's the output with the hard-coded test data as above:

```
value 1.9 gap 1
value 2.0 gap 3
value 2.1 gap 3
```

Comment: Okay, definitely ordering the numpy book now. +1

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your example is not valid code, or at least it doesn't do what you want it to do. If you have

```
for i in list1:
```

then i is not the index, but an element of list1. So first of all you would compare i and j, not list[i] and list[j].

It should be easier to use list comprehensions>

```
for i in list1:
    a = max([n for n in list2 if n < i])
    b = min([n for n in list2 if n > i])
```

You might have to add an if or two to make sure a and b exist, but it should work like this.

Comment: You don't need the second loop `for j in list2:`, do you?

Comment: +1 for list comprehensions, although generator expressions might be a bit easier to read: `a = max(n for n in list2 if n < i)`. I like how (either of) these read as being almost directly from the spec the OP gave: "a is the maximum of those elements in `list2` that are lower than this particular element of `list1`". Also, `a` and `b` will certainly exist here: if the argument to `max` or `min` amounts to an empty sequence (or, in Python 3, contain types that can't be mutually ordered), they will raise `ValueError`.

Comment: yes that's great! thank you so much. it only worked when i didn't include the second for loop, that's correct.

Comment: @wim `max` and `min` are both linear. The loop over `list1` makes it `O(len(list1) * len(list2))`. This isn't *wonderful*, but calling it obnoxious is a bit harsh.

Comment: yeah, the question has been edited - when I voted and commented it had another loop over list2 which did all of nothing, and made it O(n^3) but another user fixed it now.

Comment: @wim if you're happy that the problem you downvoted for is fixed, perhaps undoing your vote would be in order?

Comment: You don't need to generate a list inside `max()` and `min()` as they will work on sequences. So the `[ ]` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution not using numpy, bisect module or list comprehensions!
Enjoy

```
list1=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
list2=[3,6,9,12,15,18,21]

correct={4:3, 8:3, 16:3}

lower=0
for t in list1:
  print t
  difference = 0
  index = lower
  while (difference == 0 and index<len(list2)-1):
    print "consider %d < %d and %d > %d" % (list2[index],t,list2[index+1],t)
    if list2[index]<t and list2[index+1] > t:
          lower = index
          upper = index + 1
          difference = list2[upper] - list2[lower]                              
          print "%d difference %d" % (t,list2[upper] - list2[lower])
          break
    index = index +1

  if t in correct.keys():
       assert(difference == correct[t])
```